# Passing Data through URL - Need help on SOQL

Tags: javascript, button

I'm working on our Quote Request object which looks up to a Opportunity. I want to grab the RecordType from the Opportunity and pass it into the URL.
I think my SOQL statement is messed up. Can you help me fix it, I'm stuck?

I'm getting a SOQL error. [image]

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 

var myquery = "SELECT RecordTypeId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = {!Quote_Request__c.Opportunity__c} limit 1";
result = sforce.connection.query(myquery);
records = result.getArray("records");
var test = records[0];

alert(test);
var url = '/apex/QuoteRequestDetailsPage?'+
          'QuoteRequestId={!JSENCODE(Quote_Request__c.Id)}'+
          '&OpportunitySegmentId={!JSENCODE(Quote_Request__c.Opportunity_SegmentId__c)}';

window.open(url,"_self");
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought this was a pretty simple issue. In the end, it looks like this is another quirk of the Salesforce platform.

Looks like the main issue here is that, when referenced via Salesforce's expression evaluation syntax `{!myObject__c.some_Lookup__c}`, lookup fields return the Name of the related object instead of the Id.

For standard relationship fields like `CreatedBy`, for example, the API name is actually `CreatedById`. Up til now, using `CreatedBy` was something that I thought only worked in a SOQL query (used as part of a child-parent relationship to get at field data on the `User` object).

In testing on one of my sandboxes, I discovered the following

- `{!myObject__c.CreatedBy}` will return the name of the user who created the record
- `{!myObject__c.CreatedById}` will return the Id of the user who created the record

You can verify this behavior for yourself by creating a new button on any object, and using the following Javascript

```
alert("Standard lookup\nresult of CreatedBy: " +
    {!myObject__c.CreatedBy} + "\nresult of CreatedById: " +
    {!myObject__c.CreatedById}
);
```

Now that's fine and good for standard relationship fields like `CreatedById`, `AccountId`, `OpportunityId`, etc..., but what about custom lookup fields?

Weirdly enough, there appears to be very similar behavior for custom lookup fields.

In my testing, to get at the actual value (the Id) contained in a lookup field, we need to append 'Id' to the end of the field name, but before the `__c`.

`{!myObject__c.some_lookupId__c}`

Thus, to get rid of that query error, change

```
var myquery = "SELECT RecordTypeId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = {!Quote_Request__c.Opportunity__c} limit 1";
```

to

```
var myquery = "SELECT RecordTypeId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '{!Quote_Request__c.OpportunityId__c}' limit 1";
```

Note well that you will need to include the single quotes around the field expression that you're using to get at the Opportunity Id. You'll get a very similar error from your Javascript if you don't.

I don't think I've ever seen this brought up anywhere in the official documentation. If anyone knows of some official documentation for this, a comment and/or an edit would be appreciated.

Comment: Old answer with no link to official documentation but will keep looking: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008y58IAA and here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17267/get-the-id-of-a-lookup-field-for-onclick-javascript-button